# Index gymnastics in weak gravitational field

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, approximations, linearized-theory

The metric in a weak gravitational field (TT gauge) is:

$$g_{\mu\nu}=\eta_{\mu\nu}+h_{\mu\nu}$$

with

$$\eta_{\mu\nu}=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&0\\0&-1&0&0\\0&0&-1&0\\0&0&0&-1\end{pmatrix},\ h_{\mu\nu}=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0&0\\0&h_+&h_\times&0\\0&h_\times&-h_+&0\\0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$

Since $g^{\mu\nu}$ is the inverse of the matrix above we get :

$$g^{\mu\nu}=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&0\\0&-1&0&0\\0&0&-1&0\\0&0&0&-1\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0&0\\0&-h_+&-h_\times&0\\0&-h_\times&h_+&0\\0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}+\mathcal{O}(h^2)$$

This suggests that

$$\eta^{\mu\nu}=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&0\\0&-1&0&0\\0&0&-1&0\\0&0&0&-1\end{pmatrix},h^{\mu\nu}=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0&0\\0&-h_+&-h_\times&0\\0&-h_\times&h_+&0\\0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}+\mathcal{O}(h^2)$$

However when I raise and lower the indices of $h$ as follows

$$h^{\mu\nu}=g^{\mu\alpha}g^{\nu\beta}h_{\alpha\beta}=\eta^{\mu\alpha}\eta^{\nu\beta}h_{\alpha\beta}+\mathcal{O}(h^2)=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0&0\\0&h_+&h_\times&0\\0&h_\times&-h_+&0\\0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}+\mathcal{O}(h^2)$$

I get a different result (up to a sign). Which approach is wrong? I am very sure that the first with the inverse is correct, but cannot see what is wrong with the second approach?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/483498/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is wrong is the sentence that starts with “This suggests that …”, namely the sign of $h^{\mu\nu}$.

Actually, $g^{μν}=\eta^{μν}-h^{μν}+\mathcal{O}(h^2)$.
One can easily check that $(\eta^{μν}-h^{μν})(\eta_{να}+h_{να})=\delta^{\mu}_\alpha+\mathcal{O}(h^2)$.

Comment: So to be clear $h^{\mu\nu}=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0&0\\0&h_+&h_\times&0\\0&h_\times&-h_+&0\\0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$ is correct? And we write $g^{\mu\nu}=\eta^{\mu\nu}-h^{\mu\nu}$?

Comment: Yes, precisely!